# Facebook API to search public posts containing a particular hashtag

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, hashtag

Is there any Facebook Graph API to search all public posts containing a particular hashtag?

Example:- I want to search all public posts containing #ChristmasEve

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, it is not possible anymore:

> Public Post search is no longer available

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_0

There is the Public Feed API, but:

> Access to the Public Feed API is restricted to a limited set of media publishers and usage requires prior approval by Facebook. You cannot apply to use the API at this time.

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/public_feed

Comment: Is it still not available??

Comment: nope, still not available. just check out the changelog once in a while: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog